# Read a file from JQuery inside AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

Hi I'm a beginner at programming. I'm trying to put data from a json file into a variable

I want to have AngularJS put text into a html document like this

```
{{ data.text }}
```

And the text is based off of a json file I have in the app.js, so I set data using JQuery:

```
myApp.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
 $.getJSON("../static/file.json", function(data) {
   $scope.data = data;
 });
```

But nothing shows up initially. When I log $scope.data, it turns out to be undefined. But I know that my json file is correct because if I put all this code in some method that is called like

```
$scope.foo = function(){$.getJSON("../static/file.json", function(data) {
       $scope.data = data;
     });}
```

and have some button activate this, it'll work fine. But I want this to be there initially.

Comment: Why you use $.getJSON? Why not $http?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$.getJSON("/static/file.json", function(data) {
   $scope.data = data;
});
```

then it load file from web `http://xxx/static/file.json`, not file system.